# Getting file contents in Artifactory user plugin

Tags: plugins, repository, artifactory

is it possible to obtain file contents during the **beforeCreate** event in user plugin (prior to saving file in the repository)?

I'm running Artifactory 4.3.1.

Code snippet:

```
import org.artifactory.fs.FileInfo

storage {
  beforeCreate { item ->
    item = item as FileInfo

    log.warn "Analyzing item: ${item}"
    // I want to do something with the file/item contents here (for example extract ZIP)
  } 
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, this is not currently possible. At a guess, this may be to allow a user plugin to reject a deploy before the file is uploaded (i.e. via the `Expect: 100-Continue` header), but I haven't looked deeply enough into the code to know for sure.

If you need to access the file contents from a plugin, I would recommend using the `afterCreate` hook, and then getting the input stream like:

```
InputStream is = repositories.getContent(item.repoPath).inputStream
```

Of course, in this case you can't reject the upload like you can in the `beforeCreate` hook, but you can always delete the artifact if you need to.

Comment: I am not sure it is actually "sad". It's just not the right hook to use. The `beforeCreate` is just too early to get the content :)